# How can I initialize an attribute without knowing which constructors he has?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I need to implement the following class :

```
template <class Element, class Compare = std::equal_to<Element>>
class UniqueArray {
    Element* data;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int max_size;
public:
    explicit UniqueArray(unsigned int size);
    UniqueArray(const UniqueArray& other);
    ~UniqueArray();
    UniqueArray& operator=(const UniqueArray&) = delete;
    unsigned int insert(const Element& element);
    bool getIndex(const Element& element, unsigned int& index) const;
    const Element* operator[] (const Element& element) const;
    bool remove(const Element& element);
    unsigned int getCount() const;
    unsigned int getSize() const;
};
```

The problem is I can't assume that `Element` has a defualt constructor.
Assuming I can't see the implementation of `Element` class meaning that there might be other constructors but I don't know how much parameters there are and what are their types.
How can I initialize the data attribute of `UniqueArray`?

For example Element can be a Point which has a constuctor with two arguments(and no defualt constructor)
But the point is I don't know which element is being sent and I don't know what constructor this Element has.
The code supposed to be generic.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector<Element> data`?

Comment: ... or `std::set<Element>` if the elements are supposed to be unique?

Comment: reinventing a wheel aside, I dont really understand the question. Why do you want to create objects when you do not know how? Only when `insert` is called you need to insert an `Element` and there you just need to copy not call a constructor

Comment: taking the question literally, you can initialize `data` with `nullptr`, but I doubt that is what you want to hear. Can you try to clarify the question? Maybe add a piece of code where you would have to call the constructor but cannot (i dont see where that would be the case)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use STL in this part (its part of a Uni hw).
I will edit the post and try to make things more clear.

Comment: Allocate raw memory with the proper alignment, create objects as needed with placement new. (This is what `std::vector` does.)

Comment: Off topic, but the `operator[]` has a very peculiar prototype. And what is the difference between `getCount` and `getSize`?

Comment: Practically, you can’t create any objects, because there are no non-copy constructors.

Comment: You say you're not allowed to use the standard library, but you use `std::equal_to`. Are you allowed to use `std::allocator`?

Comment: @molbdnilo
getCount returns the current size .
getSize returns the max size.
As for the peculiar prototype i'm not responsible for it nor I can change it. (uni hw)

Comment: @Timo ```std:equal_to``` is the only thing I can use from the standard library

Comment: Which C++ version are you using?

Comment: @Timo c++ 11 (typing more just so its 15 char min)

Comment: Have you had a previous assignment to implement `::vector`? Can you use that?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what the constructor `UniqueArray(unsigned int size)` is supposed to do - default-construct that many elements or reserve storage?

If it only *reserves* storage, then you could use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) to decouple storage allocation from object construction, and let the user of `UniqueArray` create the elements:

```
template <class Element, class Compare = std::equal_to<Element>>
class UniqueArray {
    using storage_type = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Element), alignof(Element)>::type;
    storage_type* data;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int max_size;
public:
    explicit UniqueArray(unsigned int size) : size(0), max_size(size) {
        data = new storage_type[size];
    }
    ~UniqueArray() {
        for (unsigned pos = 0; pos < size; ++pos) {
            // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
            reinterpret_cast<Element*>(&data[pos])->~Element();
        }
        delete[] data;
    }
    Element& operator[](unsigned pos) {
        // note: needs std::launder as of C++17
        return *reinterpret_cast<Element*>(&data[pos]);
    }
    void insert(const Element& element) {
        new (&(*this)[size++]) Element(element); // placement-new
    }
    // ...
};

struct A {
    int a, b;
    A(int x) : a(x), b(x + 5) {}
};
int main() {
    UniqueArray<A> arr(3);
    arr.insert({ 2 });
    std::cout << arr[0].b << std::endl; // prints "7"
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use STL besides ```std::equal_to```.
The constructor ```UniqueArray(unsigned int size)``` should initialize all attributes

Comment: @EliranTurgeman What is an "attribute" in this context?  Do you mean "member variable"?

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Yeah, I meant member variable.

Comment: In that case you need to provide some kind of factory class (or in C++ terms, an allocator) that knows how to default-construct elements.

Answer (score 1):

First, gathering requirements:

- "`std:equal_to` is the only thing I can use from the standard library"
- There's a `max_size` and a `size` member, `getCount()` returns the current size and `getSize()` the max size (side note: this is **horrible** ...)

So I'd assume that the constructor of your class should allocate enough memory to hold `size` (the parameter) objects of the `Element` class.

The *proper* way to do this would be - as suggested in [rustyx' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59611561/1116364) - to use `std::aligned_storage`.  Since this is for a university homework and your lecturer / professor / person who wrote this assignment probably doesn't know enough about C++ to care / understand the issues you probably are best of with something like this:

```cpp
// in constructor, I repeat, THIS IS HORRIBLE!
max_size = size; // better use member initialization, though
data = reinterpret_cast<Element*>(new unsigned char[sizeof(Element) * max_size]);
```

When inserting you use placement new to create a new element as a copy:

```cpp
new (data[index_for_new_element]) Element(element);
```

For erasing you need to call the destructor manually!

```cpp
data[index_to_erase].~Element();
```

**I repeat: This is not how you'd write such code in a real application! It does *not* teach you anything valuable!**

Answer (score 0):

After a discussion with a tutor this is the way to go about it  :

`data` member variable will be initialized to an array of null pointers.
each pointer points to an Element.

We can assume that there is a copy constructor.
Whenever we want to insert a new element to the array we call `insert()` and this function inserts a copy of the element it got as an argument.

Comment: Also this doesn't look like an answer .. please add additional info to your question.

Comment: Will do, got any particular advice on which book ?

Comment: Can only link to this list: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1116364